# Sitting n families around a circular table with a condition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, binomial-coefficients

How many ways are there for sitting ***n*** families around a circular table.
Each family is a mother a father and a child.

*Condition*: The mother and father of each family should be sitting next to each other while children are not allowed to sit next to each other.

Thanks

Comment: What do you regard as distinct ways? Would you say the answer was 1 for $n=1$?

Comment: For n=1 the answer would be 2 as the conditions do not apply here and the number of arrangement of 3 people around a circular table is (3-1)!=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you regard arrangements obtained by rotations and reflections as equivalent.

Start with the location of $M_1$ and choose the direction by taking the next person as $F_1$. Then there are $(n-1)!2^{n-1}$ ways of arranging the other parents and $n!$ ways of fitting the children in the $n$ gaps between them. So total $n!(n-1)!2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Arranging n couples of F's and M's should be (n-1)! multiplied by 2^n as each couple could be sitted as MF or FM.
Now we need to arrange the n children and that gives us n! options.
To conclude, (n-1)!* 2^n * n!. Could you spot the mistake I am making?

Comment: need divide for circle rotations

Comment: @miniparser I see. Could you elaborate more please?

Comment: @Tamir The two questions of definition are: (1) do you regard 1,2,3,4 as the same arrangement as 2,3,4,1 (ie differ only in rotation); (2) do you regard 1, 2, 3, 4 as the same arrangement as 1,4,3,2 (ie going the opposite way round the circle). I assumed the answer was yes in both cases. If your answer to (2) is No, then you need to double the number.

Comment: I think divide by 3n

Comment: @Tamir. There is a third question. Is a child required to sit next to one of its parents? I assume not. But if it is, then the answer is different.

Comment: (1) Yes  ,   (2) No,    (3) No.      Using the answer you provided multiplied by 2. The final answer I got to is: 2^n * n! * (n-1)!

Comment: @Tamir. That is fine (assuming that a child does not need to sit next to one of its parents).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:-

Let us name the mother=$M$,father=$F$ and child=$C$.

As the mother and father sits together,group one family into two parts-$(M,F);(C)$.(How many groups can be formed out of *n* families if one family breaks up into $2$ groups?).

Now,arrange *n* number of $(M,F)$ and $(C)$'s around the table by using circular permutation formula that *x* number of  objects can be arranged into $(x-1)!$ ways.

Hope my answer helps!!

Comment: Thought 2:
There are four options to sit the first family MFC,FMC,CMF,CFM then for the next n-1 families I have only two options left (for example, MFCCFM won't comply with condition while MFCMFC or MFCFMC will) which is 4*2^n-1.
All we have left are the kids that have (n-1)! options to be seated.
Final answer: 4*2^n-1*(n-1)! = 2^n+1 * (n-1)! . Is this anyway around?

Comment: @Tamir Yeah...you are on the right way I think...